# Do manuscripts sent for submission in Word format need to be already in two column or a specific font?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, formatting

I am reading the guidelines for authors on a research journal which is part of Wiley. In the guidelines for authors it is only mentioned it should be submitted in Word format but nothing about font, font size, and if it should be already in two-column format.

Also it says figures should go at the end of the Word file, but I want to insert two figures in the same page to avoid paying twice the color page charge.

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Formatting guidelines are almost always available via the publisher's website.

Comment: @aeismail I read the style guide and formatting guidelines but there is no mention to font size or font type.

Comment: If there aren't instructions, pick a "neutral" typeface and size (for example, Helvetica 12 point is the default in Europe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Journals typically provides guidelines as to what formats are possible, for example, Word and/or LaTeX for text, eps, pdf, TIFF; JPG etc. for graphics. Wiley, for example, provides a [guide line](http://authorservices.wiley.com/bauthor/illustration.asp) for graphics that is general in their [Author Services section](http://authorservices.wiley.com/default.asp).

Adhering to the requested file formats may be quite important although with Wiley, I have noted that they accept common formats for graphics although they are not specifically mentioned in the general guide line. As for formatting of text, I would (as editor for a journal) argue that

- you should keep it as simple as possible
- do not attempt fancy formatting, keep it tidy and readable
- make sure your figures are of good quality and reproduced well in the files you provide
- follow any *instructions for authors*, or equivalent, the journal may provide (if such IFAs do not exist, then use a standard font and make, for example headings clearly visible against the main text and check the journal for reference system and formatting)

Answer (score 4):

The review formatting and the final, camera-ready formatting are often quite different. You will probably get a chance to reformat it for publication after it is reviewed. If you have any doubt about that, you should contact the editor.

Answer (score 2):

The most common and universally acceptable formatting for scientific manuscripts is Times New Roman, 12 point, 1 inch margins all around, one column. Certainly don't attempt two-column format! That happens much later, during the typesetting process.

Regarding figure placement, that is also something to discuss with the editor or copy-editor much later, after the paper is accepted.

Right now you are preparing the paper to be read by reviewers. They don't care what page your figures are on, and they certainly don't want to deal with two-column formatting!